# How can I trigger a workflow on pull request specifying base and head branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this workflow file in my main branch:

```yaml
name: WorkflowTest

on:
  pull_request:
```

The workflow is getting triggered whenever a pull request is created from any branch to any branch.

I want the workflow to be triggered only when the pull request is created having base:main and compare:xyx, how can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request

Answer (score 1):

To filter by base branch, you can use `pull_request.branches`; to filter on the head branch, you need an `if` condition on the job (see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request)). For example:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  job:
    if: github.head_ref == 'xyx'
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - run: echo "This PR was opened from 'xyx' into 'main'"
```